# I want an android app that sync with watsapp or SMS messenger and automatically response to the user/client

Tags: android-applicationinfo

I am working for a non profit organisation and Our Project needs an android app (to develop a brief intervention that uses mobile text/voice messaging to address 
problematic drinking among adolescents.) This app should woks as a bidirectional and better if it collaborate with watsapp. so that we will get responses quickly via watsapp and automatically our apps should tell questions base on 
his/her answer. Also it should store conversation data  into the database.

Comment: If anyone has any idea regarding such apps, Kindly help us, or if possible help us in developing this app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from the friendly chat app based on Firebase. Take a look here https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0 . For the "auto reply" functionality you will have to write your own cloud function. Read some docs about that

Comment: Thanks Nicola,  I'll start with this.